# Strange Match behaviour with data tables/named ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a workbook with three worksheets, each containing a data table with about 4500 rows.  I'm trying to join the three tables into one using Index/Match.

I add a column to Table1 with the following formula:
    `=INDEX(Table2[@DataColumn],MATCH(Table1[@KeyColumn],Table2[@KeyColumn],0))`

This seems to work fine for the first 2800 rows, but then from that point on it's returning #N/A.  Stepping through the formula evaluation, it looks like the formula is evaluating the match like this:
`Match("Key Value",Sheet2!$B$2883,0)`

I would have expected to see it evaluate like this:
`Match("Key Value",Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4500,0)`

I know I can do this with VLookup, but I'm trying to learn Index/Match for a simple case like this before I start applying it to more complex situations.

Comment: Looking at my data, the spot where it breaks is precisely where the rows no longer match 1 for 1.  Looks like it's a miracle that the first 2800 worked.

Comment: The `@`'s in your structured references refer to "On the current row".  Try `=INDEX(Table2[DataColumn],MATCH(Table1[@KeyColumn],Table2[KeyColumn],0))`

Comment: That's a pretty key pointer of something I didn't understand about table references...Thanks!  Wish you'd added it as an answer, but I'll try to write it up myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the original formula is that ranges are being mis-referenced.  Table2[@DataColumn] references a specific entry, while Table2[DataColumn] references the range.

The correct formula is `=INDEX(Table2[DataColumn],MATCH(Table1[@KeyColumn],Table2[Ke‌​yColumn],0))`